# HOW TO FIX: K8 job stoped and is not schedule any more

Tags: kubernetes, cron, devops, kubernetes-jobs

I had to stop a job in k8 by killing the pod, and now the job is not schedule anymore.

```
# Import
  - name: cron-xml-import-foreman
    schedule: "*/7 * * * *"
    args:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      /var/www/bash.sh; /usr/bin/php /var/www/import-products.php -->env=prod;
    resources:
      request_memory: "3Gi"
      request_cpu: "2"
      limit_memory: "4Gi"
      limit_cpu: "4"
```

Error :

> Warning  FailedNeedsStart  5m34s (x7883 over 29h)  cronjob-controller 
>   Cannot determine if job needs to be started: Too many missed start
>   time (> 100). Set or decrease .spec.startingDeadlineSeconds or check
>   clock skew.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/?source=post_page---------------------------#cron-job-limitations):

> If startingDeadlineSeconds is set to a large value or left unset (the
>   default) and if concurrencyPolicy is set to Allow, the jobs will
>   always run at least once.

---

> A CronJob is counted as missed if it has failed to be created at its
>   scheduled time. For example, If concurrencyPolicy is set to Forbid and
>   a CronJob was attempted to be scheduled when there was a previous
>   schedule still running, then it would count as missed.

---

And regarding the [concurrencyPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy)

> It specifies how to treat concurrent executions of a job that is
>   created by this cron job.

Check your `CronJob` configuration and adjust those values accordingly.

Please let me know if that helped.